# JavaScript validation for multiple functions?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a JavaScript function for a form. The code is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function verify() {
    if (isNaN(document.form1.exp_amount.value) == true) {
        alert("Invalid Block Amount");
        return false;
    } else if ((document.form1.exp_name.value).length == 0) {
        alert("Block Exp is left Blank!");
        return false;
    } else if ((document.form1.exp_amount.value).length == 0) {
        alert("Block Amount is left Blank!");
        return false;
    } else {
        document.form1.submit();
        return true;
    }
}
</script>
```

Now I have to provide Alphabet Validation for it, which I have it in a separate JS function:

```
<script language="javascript" >
function checkName() {
    re = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    if (re.test(document.exp_name.form1.value)) {
        alert('Valid Name.');
    } else {
        alert('Invalid Name.');
    }
}
</script>
```

If I want to have Alphabet validation inside function `verify()`, how could I do it? Are there any other ways?

Comment: Have you ever considered indenting your code?!

Answer (score 1):

Please change your validation and form to this which will allow submission of the form if valid and not if errors. The following code is in my opinion *canonical* and will work on all browsers that support regular expressions (which was introduced in JS1.1 in 1996 with NS3.0) - please note that javascript does not support dashes in names unless you quote the field name in the script. The code does not need the form to be named since it passes the form object in the call *(this)* and uses the object in the function as *theForm*

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Canonical forms validation without jQuery</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var validName = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
function checkName(str) {
  return validName.test(str);
}

function verify(theForm) {
  // note: theForm["..."] is short for theForm.elements["..."];
  var amount = theForm["exp_amount"].value; 
  if(amount ==""){
    alert("Block Amount is left blank");
    theForm["exp_amount"].focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (isNaN(amount)) {
    alert("Invalid Block Amount");
    theForm["exp_amount"].focus();
    return false;
  }

  var name = theForm["exp_name"].value; 
  if(name.length==0) {
    alert("Block Exp is left Blank!");
    theForm["exp_name"].focus();
    return false;
  }
  if(!checkName(name)) {
    alert("Block Exp is invalid!");
    theForm["exp_name"].focus();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form onsubmit="return verify(this)">
Amount: <input type="text" name="exp_amount" value="" /><br />
Name: <input type="text" name="exp_name" value="" /><br />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have the input text fields as Expenditure Name (exp_name- text), Block Amount (exp_amount-Integer) and the form name is form1. Could you edit this info in your coding. Im new to this. So that i can be more clear whats happening in the script. cheers

Comment: @Dinzy - sure. If you have dashes in the names, then the code changes. Please edit the text of your question to reflect the actual situation in such cases. I will update my code. My code does not need the name of the form since we pass the form object in the verify function

Comment: @Dinzy, is the -integer part of the field name and is it Integer or integer, i.e. upper or lower case I ?

Comment: Removed the -integer and -text , i just used to say that exp_amount is of integer type and exp_name is of text type

Comment: @Dinzy, ok, that was confusing. Anyway, my script is reflecting reality and time for you to test and accept and vote up if you can.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function verify()
{
    if(isNaN(document.form1.exp_amount.value)==true)
    {
         alert("Invalid Block Amount");
         return false;
    }
    else if((document.form1.exp_name.value).length==0)
    {
         alert("Block Exp is left Blank!");
         return false;
    }
    else if((document.form1.exp_amount.value).length==0)
    {
         alert("Block Amount is left Blank!");
         return false;
    }
    else if(!(/^[A-Za-z]+$/.test(document.form1.exp_amount.value))) //ADD THIS
    {
        alert('Invalid Name');
        return false;
    }

     document.form1.submit();
     return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Since, The form name , field name is not provided for the alphabet validation. will it work?

Comment: @Dinzy sorry it was copy-paste mistake :D

Comment: @village, I have tried your way, Its not showing the alert box! it is submitting the value!..:(  form action='blockexp.php' name='form1' method='POST' onsubmit='return verify()'> <- i have this in the post action of Form

Comment: Ok.. now i got the alert box invalid name, But still the values are getting submitted.. lol

Comment: @Village, Its still getting submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Simply return false or true inside your `checkName` function:

```
function checkName()
{
    re = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    if(re.test(document.exp_name.form1.value))
    {
        alert('Valid Name.');
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Invalid Name.');
        false;
    }
}
```

Then call it and check the result.

```
    ...

    else if((document.form1.exp_amount.value).length==0)
    {
        alert("Block Amount is left Blank!");
        return false;
    }

    else if (!checkName()) {
        return false;
    }

    else
    {
        document.form1.submit();
        return true;
    }
```

As an aside, there are many ways your code can be cleaned up and improved. I don't want to get into them now, but if you'd like to discuss it, just leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your checkName() function to

```
function checkName()
{
re = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
if(re.test(document.exp_name.form1.value))
{
     alert('Valid Name.');
     return true;
}
else
{
    alert('Invalid Name.');
    return false;

}

}
```

And add

```
else if(!checkName()){ return false;}
```

to your validation code just before the form submit

Comment: form should be submitted if all validations pass. But using `return checkName()` will not submit even if check passes as it will return true.